# How do I end a neural network to produce regression output?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to neural nets...but I have an RNN set up.  The net is generic, so I can output and input in as many dimensions as I want...so this isn't a problem.

However, when it comes to regression, I am terminating my prediction with a final tanh function.

Is this the activation of the terminal node of a regression net?  If it is, how does one convert this to an actual regression (since it will be a value between 1 and -1...)?

Or do I need to normalize the whole function... (I guess this seems problematic for anything that generally increases or decreases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an output for a regression problem you need to remove the softmax/tanh/logistic unit in the last layer to get the linear combination of the activations of the previous layer with the weight vectors. Then you can use a suitable cost function such as Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) or Mean Squared Error (MSE) to get the deviations of the output with your desired target.

**References**

> - [Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation)
> - [Mean Squared Error (MSE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error)
> - [A Neural Network used For a Regression Problem (Coded Example)](https://heuristically.wordpress.com/2011/11/17/using-neural-network-for-regression/)